# can Jackson serialize to a Java Set<> in RESTEasy?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using JAX-RS with RESTEasy and Jackson as a provider. I know from past experience (if I remember correctly) that I can have Jackson serialize my `FooBar` POJOs to a Java `List<FooBar>`, like this, generating either text or JSON:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<FooBar> getFooBars() throws IOException, WebApplicationException;
```

But can Jackson handle `Set<FooBar>` as well?

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<Set> getFooBars() throws IOException, WebApplicationException;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackson will look at actual type of the instance during serialization, changing the return type of the method won't make a difference - you can change it to `Object` if you want. Deserialization is another matter however.

Jackson will handle all `Iterable`s the same way, it'll serialize as an array